# Storing values into a multi dimensional array

Tags: java, testng

I have a method as below

```
public Object[][] createData() {
    return new Object[][] {
               {"data1"},{"data2"},{"data3"}
    };
}
```

Now let's say I have multiple data (upto data50) in a properties file and I'm storing all the values in a list inside above mentioned method. What is the best way to return the object without hard coding the data values inside the method (Like data4, data5, data6....)

Comment: Why are you having data for array in properties file? Properties file are used to store data in the form of `key:value` pair, appropriate for `Map`

Comment: @RohitJain : Alright let's say I only have data in a  text file or spreadsheet and I'm reading the text file / spreadsheet and storing the values in a list.

Comment: And do you really need an array of array? It seems like an array would suffice.

Comment: @RohitJain : yes. that's how testng want's it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use a loop?

```
Object[][] data = new Object[50][1];

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    data[i] = new Object[]{getData()};
}
```

`data` is an array of arrays (a "2D-array"). In other words, each element `data[i]` of `data` is *itself* an `Object[]`. Consequently, we can assign `new Object[]{getData()}` (an array) to `data[i]`.

Comment: Well, the real magic is in `getData()` which is what OP wants to know.

Comment: how is that in  data[i] = new Object[]{getData()};  data is one dimensional? can you pls explain?

Comment: @RohitJain : I agree with arshajii's solution. but I already tried this after a bit of googling. but I want to know how it works

Comment: @user1629109 I added some more explanation; please let me know if anything is still unclear.